# Why does my python regex code not work properly?

Tags: python, html, regex, html-parsing

Good evening.
I got the following html code:

```
<tr>
   <td>value:</td>
   <td>0</td>
</tr>
```

This code is part of a full html webpage.
I want to parse the value in the second td-tag.

This is my attempt:

```
pattern = re.compile('<td>value:</td>.*?<td>(.*?)</td>', re.S)
value = pattern.search(source_code).group(1)
```

`source_code` is the full webpage source code.

When I run this code, I get this message:
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Do not parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Instead, use a specialized tool, an html parser, like [`BeautifulSoup`](http://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.org/en/latest/):

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> data = """<tr>
...    <td>value:</td>
...    <td>0</td>
... </tr>"""
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
>>> soup.find('tr')('td')[1].text
u'0'
>>> soup.find('td', text='value:').find_next_sibling('td').text
u'0'
```

Comment: Oh cool, I didn't thought of that. Thanks!